# Self paid Insurance Premiums and taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, insurance, hsa

Currently my employer proivdes a Health Insurance Allowance (which I understand is really just added compensation), but I am wondering if it is possible to somehow shield that money similar to a pre-tax premium.  Originally I had thought I would be able to pay my premiums (for an HSA qualified plan) out of the HSA and just have my employer contribute to that HSA.  But for some reason this isn't allowed?  What other options do I have along these lines.

Instead of claiming individual health insurance at tax filing time, have it deducted pre-tax.

Comment: I am in the same boat.  Unfortunately, you can only claim premiums paid that exceed 10% of your AGI, at least that is my understanding of it.  If you are self employed you get more options.

Answer (score 1):

The tax incentives for employer sponsored health insurance were designed to incentivize employers to provide the insurance and for employees to purchase the insurance.  Since your situation does not meet the requirements to take advantage of this incentive, you can not.  In the near future you should be able to take part in the government sponsored exchanges.  This may spur changes in how this works.